# Работа с множественными файлами в bash

Tags: linux, bash, for, ос, grep

Необходимо создать скрипт, который будет в корне условного гита искать в папках с маской *Shared* файл Module.mtd. И выдергивать от туда определенные значения. С записью в файл с XML структурой...

Если с первой частью понятно как-то все, то со второй уже сложнее.
На баше написал такое чудо:

```
find . -iname "Module.mtd" | grep "Shared" >> .parse # находит все нужные файлы по маске
```

Итоговое содержание у файла .parse:

```
./conult.Shared/Module.mtd
./teysfg.Shared/Module.mtd
./Goverment.Shared/Module.mtd
./testtoprod.Shared/Module.mtd
./stagestate.Shared/Sungero.RecordManagementUI/Module.mtd
./prodstate.Shared/Sungero.Shell/Module.mtd
./conv.Shared/Module.mtd
```

**Вот тут я подзастрял как-то**

Теперь надо как-то по очереди открывать файлы (путь которых у нас есть в файле .parse) и брать у них определенные значения, допустим
"NameGuid" (1 совпадение (в файле их порядка 10))

Для этого я подозреваю что надо использовать `cat + grep + cut` чтоб выдернуть определенное значение в переменную, которую позже записать в файл, в моем случае это будет

```
GUID=$(cat ./conult.Shared/Module.mtd | grep "NameGuid" | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort | head -n 1) | echo $GUID
```

Команда выше выведет верхний главные Guid который мне нужен. Но как правильно обьединить 2 команды для перебора?

Усредненно должно быть 1 скрипт создает файл с относительными путями, а второй скрипт, должен будет в цикле(? вот тут вопрос, как правильнее будет) перебирать файлы с путями из .parse и выдергивать из них значение GUID. И заносить в xml

Может кто-нибудь подсказать как реализовать цикл который будет делать что-то подобное? Не чего-то похожего найти на просторах интернета не могу. И да, ответ на первый вопрос "Почему именно на bash?" - Необходимо использовать только нативные способы, без python, GO и powershell.

Буду крайне блоагодарен за ответ C:

Comment: `find . -wholename '*Shared*' -iname "Module.mtd" -exec grep "NameGuid" {} \; | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort` - что нибудь такое попробуйте

Comment: Если речь идёт о Git, так и пользуйтесь его гораздо лучшими возможностями, как то: 1) используйте индекс, а не рабочую копию; 2) научитесь команде `git ls-files`.

Comment: @ipatev_nn, очередной «совет» (несмотря на отсутствие работы с Git) про `grep` в XML... меня всегда удивляет, откуда эта чушь размножается?

Comment: Для работы с XML используйте `xmllint` или другие утилиты, поддерживающие XPath.

Comment: @0andriy, очередной "совет" про "очередной совет", а от меня то что нужно? Есть ответ правильный? Напиши его.

Comment: @ipatev_nn, не множить и так уже заваленные интернеты такими «советами»? Если что, я в комментариях ТС изложил ключевые слова для домашней работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала отвечу на комментарии к вопросу:

1. git нет возможности юзать
2. grep в xml это не кощунство, а способ выбраться из ситуации, т.к НЕТ возможности юзать xmllint или что-то другое, в самом конце я это уточнил:

> Необходимо использовать только нативные способы, без python, GO и powershell.

Была бы возможность юзать хоть что-то другое кроме нативных UNIX утилит, вопрос бы не задавался, ведь людское время самый ценный ресурс.

А решение оказалось вполне себе простым и самое главное, безотказным

```
find . -iname "Module.mtd" | grep "Shared" >> .parse # тут мы записываем все пути до необходимых нам файлов построчно

STRINGS=$(wc -l .parse | cut -d ' ' -f 1) # Тут мы узнаем итоговое количество строк, которые содержатся в нашем файле со всеми путями.
```

Если все вышеописанное похоже на костыль, то дальше будет больше.

Теперь нам надо построчно брать ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫЙ путь и открывать там файлы, для наших манипуляций, а т.к нам необходимо перебирать множество файлов, запиливаем цикл

```
for (( i=1; i <= $STRINGS; i++ ))
OPEN=$(cat .parse | head -n$i | tail -n1) && GUID=$(cat $OPEN | grep "NameGuid" | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort | head -n 1) && echo $GUID
#1 часть цикла получает в виде строки относительный путь файла, вторая часть по относительному пути оперирует файлом и загоняет Необходимый мне guid в переменную.
```

Если есть более рациональное решение, то я хочу его увидеть C: